# SMF - Upgrading 1-19 to 2-7 (upgrade.php)

Tags: php, mysql, forum, smf

i decided to move my 1.1.19 to 2.07 and move to new directory.
but i couldn't upgrade my forum correctly. because:

**repair_settings.php - (in bottom of page we got some error)**

> Notice: Undefined index: database_error in
>   /homepages/5/d394578306/htdocs/ResidentEvil/Sources/Subs-Db-mysql.php
>   on line 572
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function allowedTo() in
>   /homepages/5/d394578306/htdocs/ResidentEvil/Sources/Subs-Db-mysql.php
>   on line 573

**Upgrade.php - (we have many error on this page)**

> Notice: Undefined index: upgrade_progress in
>   /homepages/5/d394578306/htdocs/ResidentEvil/upgrade.php on line 3488

same error but on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're missing some files. Reupload all the Sources dir and the upgrade files with a software like WinSCP. Avoid FileZilla.

Comment: i did, but nothing changed, still got errors. all files uploaded, im sure. but look like upgrade.php can't load source files. any other solution?